# Active Admin Model Updation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

Im using active admin gem.

My doubt is can i create a new column in another table, while updating a table using active admin gem.

If possible show me some tutorials..

Like im in user.rb model.. and im editing it via active admin.. I have entered a name and while saving i want this name to get saved in another model too.at the same time.

Comment: clarify your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try like this:

```
controller do
 def create
   create! # this will do default operations
   # Do your stuff here
 end
end
```

In active admin internally they are using [inherited resources](https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources).

or try like

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  after_create do |user|
  product.creator = user.name
 end
end
```